# Count of matching values in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can I get the count of matching values in the same row? I have a similar setup to below and I would expect to get an answer of 2 because of matches in the first and third row

```
A  |  B
-------    
a  |  a
b  |  k
c  |  c
d  |  z
e  |  i
```

I am looking to do this with a single formula and tried

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5)
```

But that doesn't give me the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5=B1:B5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Both @TimBiegeleisen and @CallumDA give this formula as an answer, but I'll give some explanation in case it's useful and helps you on future work:

The formula is `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5=B1:B5))`. Let's examine it piece-by-piece, starting from the inside and working our way out:

1. `A1:A5=B1:B5`:
   This gives you an array of Boolean (i.e., TRUE/FALSE) values indicating whether the equality is satisfied. For the data in your question, it looks like this: `{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}`. We're interested in counting the number of `TRUE` values in that array.
2. `--`:
   This is a convention that you'll see a lot in Excel. It's a handy way to coerce Boolean values from `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0`, respectively. Applying it to the array above gives us this array: `{1;0;1;0;0}`.
3. `SUMPRODUCT`:
   From the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e): `SUMPRODUCT` "Multiplies corresponding components in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products." If you give it a single array as an argument, it will simply sum the elements of the array. That's what we're doing here. So the result is `2`. Alternatively, we could have used the `SUM` function, but with an array, the `SUM` function would require use of CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. `SUMPRODUCT` handles arrays without that extra step.